# how do I connect to a VPN with ipsec?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, vpn, ipsec

I created a config file for my FritzBox 7390 after [this german tutorial](http://www.blog.happytec.at/index.php?mode=view&id=273)

Now I want to configure my Network-Manager but there is no option for ipsec.

Do I need additional packages?

---

I tried to install [L2TP Ipsec VPN-Applet, a GUI for openswan](https://launchpad.net/~werner-jaeger/+archive/ppa-werner-vpn) but it doesent start, cause on Xubuntu there is no Unity Icon possible. How can I install this on Xubuntu?

---

Update:

I installed

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
```

and then I got the option to add a Cisco-compatible VPN-Client (vpnc) but I couldnt configure it, so it works. Do I need something in the *extended settings*?

these are the configuration screens in german:

[image]

[image]

[image: extended settings]

Comment: http://linuxundich.de/ubuntu/update-auf-fritzos-6-0-macht-nun-das-einrichten-eines-fritzbox-vpns-komplett-ohne-windows-moeglich/

Answer (score 2):

You can install vpnc with `sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc`.  This will add VPN functionality to 'Network Connections' in your system settings.  From a couple of web searches, vpnc with FritzBox is a common config.  Personally, I prefer OpenVPN on Tomato or pfsense, as they're much easier to configure, but good luck w/IPsec!

Answer (score 1):

The current best option in **2018** is [network-manager-l2tp](https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp) which works well with **StrongSwan**.

See my notes for using the [NetworkManager applet to connect a `l2tp ipsec vpn`](https://serverfault.com/questions/344768/strongswan-ipsec-ubuntu-ignoring-informational-payload-type-no-proposal-chosen/901183#901183).

& additional notes for "[use this connection only for resources on its network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667544/vpn-client-routing-when-use-this-connection-only-for-resources-on-its-network/1014163#1014163)" (only routing traffic for the remote network down the vpn).