# vpn client routing when "use this connection only for resources on its network" is checked

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I cannot access to servers like 192.168.12.123 from vpn if "use this connection only for resources on its network" is checked in vpn settings/ipv4 settings/routes, but I can if this flag is unchecked.

routes address/netmask:

```
192.168.0.0 255.0.0.0
10.0.0.0    255.0.0.0
```

flag is unchecked:

```
route -n                                                                    
Kernel IP routing table                                                        
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.35.5.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
168.68.168.6    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
168.68.168.6    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

flag is checked

```
route -n                                                                    
Kernel IP routing table                                                     
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface 
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0 
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 ppp0 
10.35.5.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0 
168.68.168.6    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0 
168.68.168.6    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0 
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

main difference is gateway.

0.0.0.0 if flag is unchecked and 192.168.0.1 otherwise.

How to change gateway for checked flag?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add default gateway with command

by the ip address

```
sudo ip route add default via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - represent ip of vpn server

or by interface

```
sudo ip route add default dev ppp0
```

This can be done manually from terminal when you are connected to vpn.

Second solution is to make script to chance default gw when vpn is connected

Then create script witch will be executed when interface `ppp0` go up.

Create script for `ppp0` interface

```
sudo nano /etc/ppp/if-up.d/script
```

put in script this

```
    # Check for specific interface if desired
    [ "$IFACE" != "ppp0" ] || exit 0
    # trigger vpn connection
    ip route add default dev ppp0
```

Save and exit.

Make script called `script` with execute permissions 755

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

Explanation

When `vpn` connection will established and `ppp0` interface is up script will run and set default device to `ppp0`

Also you can manually add route to resource on `vpn` site

```
sudo ip route add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy dev ppp0
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - represent host/network

`yy` - represent network mask

example:

add route to host `10.35.5.181` trough `ppp0`

```
 sudo ip route add 10.35.5.181/32 dev ppp0
```

add route to network range `10.35.5.0` with mask `255.255.255.0` trough `ppp0`

```
 sudo ip route add 10.35.5.0/24 dev ppp0
```

This also can be done in `Network Manager`. On same places where is `use this connection only for resources on its network` you can add route.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `route` to match the routing table on the `remote` server:

[image: REMOTE Routing Table]

which will give you a `local` routing table of:

[image: LOCAL Routing Table]

I also have some notes for [connecting to a `L2TP VPN`](https://serverfault.com/questions/344768/strongswan-ipsec-ubuntu-ignoring-informational-payload-type-no-proposal-chosen/901183#901183)